# Read Do not Disturb setting in IOS6

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6

Is there a way to programatically read the new Do not Disturb mode in IOS6?

Answer (score 2):

Nope, not possible using public API.

Comment: I hate to knock you off your `1337` reputation, but... :)

Comment: Haha, did that to myself I guess. I'll make a bad post somewhere else to make up for it ;-)