# Do Not Disturb API for iOS7

Tags: ios7

I know there wasn't a Do Not Disturb API for iOS6. (See [Read Do not Disturb setting in IOS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643551/read-do-not-disturb-setting-in-ios6)) but is there one for iOS7?

I've not read all the headers :-) but I've certainly not seen any mention of this in all the readings I've see so far. But proving you *can't* do something is of course hard.

Comment: How do you know that there's API for it on iOS 7 without reading the docs? I really don't think there's a new API for this.

Comment: One can't read ALL the docs now, can you? I know I can't...

Comment: But you must have read *somewhere* to state that "there's one for iOS7". Or was that a question?

Comment: LOL, I see it now. Added the ? to the question. Good catch, thanks!

Comment: This is why Apple publishes an [API Differences](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/releasenotes/General/iOS70APIDiffs/index.html) page when releasing new iOS versions.